# Soldering wires to the small pins of a socket

Tags: soldering

There is a laser diode which I need to couple to a special socket for mounting.

Here is the laser diode where you can see its male pins:

[image]

This is the socket:

[image]

I need to solder the male pins of this socket to wires but the pins are very small. [Here](https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/ebf0cd5bd5f4659c-B3BBB3DD-93BE-545C-D6FD0B8F56A39EEC/S7060R-AutoCADPDF.pdf) is its datasheet.

Are the usual soldering techniques OK for this socket?

Comment: It depends on the type of plastic, many will melt easily. You want to use as little heat as possible. You can mitigate the risk of melting by plugging it into the mate while soldering. Then, if the plastic melts slightly, the pins will remain in the correct position until the plastic hardens again.

Comment: @Mattman944 To be picky - if you have to do something like that, you've already botched the solder job (yes I use similar tricks too but it's not recommended). In this case it seems to be a part intended for through-hole mounting. Using the solder cup part as stated in one answer should significantly reduce the risk of melting the plastic, since less heat will be needed for the joint to wet.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is supposed to be mounted on a PCB.

There are versions of this socket type intended to have wires soldered to them, like this one:

[image]
<sup>(Source: [Meredith Instruments](https://www.mi-lasers.com/product/laser-diode-electrical-connection-socket/))</sup>

It would be best to get that type of socket if you want to connect wires.

If you must solder wires to the one you have, you could consider making a small PCB for it and solder the wires to that, or simply solder wires to the pins carefully, making sure the plastic doesn't melt, and use heatshrink tube to isolate and strengthen things a bit, and see if it works well enough for you.

It will be mechanically weak, what with the 0.2 mm diameter pins having to hold a moving cable. You could try some larger diameter heatshrink that goes over the plastic bit of the socket and all the wires, filled with glue if possible, in addition to heatshrink around the individual pins/wires.

Comment: I find that when soldering connectors it's sometimes helpful to install the mating connector before soldering. In this case that would be a laser diode (best to use a dead one). It keeps the metal components from moving in the plastic if it softens due to the heat.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the connector on the laser assembly, it appears that the right-hand side of the connector (the sockets) are what mates to the laser.

Simple lap joints will work well with the connector you show the picture of.  Carefully tin the pins, tin the wires, add just a tiny bit of flux to either the pins or wires, then just lay each wire on the pin and heat until you have a good joint.

Slide heatshrink over each conductor / pin.  I would also consider using adhesive-lined 3:1 shrink ratio heat shrink tubing over the pins and wires just to provide mechanical strength.